# O cifrão ($) não funciona para interpolar uma string em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

Estou usando um código que usa o cifrão (`$`) do JavaScript, só que ao usar o cifrão ele dá erro no console e o código para buscar os dados de uma API acaba não funcionando. O que preciso fazer para o JavaScript reconhecer o cifrão e realizar a interpolação corretamente?

```
async addRepository(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       const repoTnput = this.inputEl.value;

       if (repoTnput.length === 0)
            return;
       
       const response = await api.get('/repos/${repoInput}');
       const { name, description, html_url, owner: { avatar_url } } = response.data;
       // ...
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

O que está procurando chama-se [Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings).

Template strings é um literal string que permitem expressões embutidas.
Esse literal é delimitado por acentos graves `` ` `` ao invés das tradicionais aspas simples `'` ou aspas duplas `"`.

O template string também pode conter espaços reservados delimitados por um cifrão `$` e chaves `{}` em torno de uma expressão que será inserida na string.

Exemplo:

```js
let a = 3;
let b = 4;

console.log(`a + b = ${a+b} e a * b = ${a*b}`);
```

No seu código:

```
const response = await api.get(`/repos/${repoInput}`);
```

Comment: @hkotsubo, como conseguiu essa mágica?

Comment: Assim: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55437/401803