# Problemas com cifrão $ em JavaScript no VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, template

Toda vez que faço um código que vai cifrão ${} ele não funciona, como se não reconhecesse, não sei como solucionar isso, peço ajuda. Já baixei conversores de string de modelo mas não consegui.

Segue o código, é um exemplo simples está em HTML, mas no JS é exatamente o mesmo problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/78768/112052

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/458004/137387

Answer (score -3, accepted):

o uso do cifrão, conforme você mencionou, no JavaScript, nós chamamos de Template Strings/Template Literals, o conjunto ${} é usado para passar uma expressão, e deve estar contida entre duas crases, veja um exemplo abaixo:

```
console.log(`Quinze é ${a + b} e não ${2 * a + b}.`);
```

Observe se está passando a crase em volta,  outro detalhe é que entre ${} só pode ser passado expressões, como comparações, expressões numéricas, entre outros. Se ainda, assim, não conseguir resolver o problema, uma outra possibilidade é dar uma olhada no MDN Web Docs, segue o link do assunto em questão para você poder dar uma olhada

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Link no CodePen: https://codepen.io/liandro-wesley/pen/MWvOwQZ?editors=1011

Comment: Olá Liandro, muito obrigada por responder, muito mesmo! Estou iniciando no aprendizado sobre o assunto a respeito, e desde que o professor inseriu essas templates com cifrão eu estou tendo dificuldades em executar, estarei mandando um código simples que tentei executar como exemplo, está em HTML somente, mas no JS também estou com o mesmo problema. Desde já agradeço a atenção e a ajuda.

Comment: Liandro Wesley, veja no [nosso modelo de comportamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) que cumprimentos e agradecimentos devem ser evitados nas publicações. Outra cousa não oriente os usuários a usarem o site como mecanismo de [depuração ou revisão de código](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/514/o-que-fazer-com-perguntas-que-apenas-procuram-code-review-for-typos/518#518) isso está fora do nosso escopo, o autor do código deve ser [autossuficiente para depurar o próprio código](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7785/como-debugar-programas-pequenos).

Comment: Quando verificar que o usuário ainda não sabe como usar ferramentas de depuração use o campo de comentários para orientar e instruir e não o campo de respostas.

Comment: Vitória, segue a solução para o seu problema. Estarei editando esta resposta colocando um código de exemplo