# como alterar o tamanho da fonte diretamente na variável JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
function matematica(){

        var peso = document.getElementById("peso") ;
        var altura = document.getElementById("altura");
        var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");

        var p = Number(peso.value);
        var a = Number(altura.value);

        var calculo = p/(a*a);

        if(peso.value.length == 0 || altura.value.length == 0){
            alert("Digite os dados na Tabela")}
        else if(calculo < 16){
            resultado.innerHTML = "Seu IMC é de " + calculo + "<br>" + "<br>" +" Sua classifição é Magreza Grau III procure um especialista"
```

Como posso alterar o tamanho da font diretamente na variável ? por exemplo quero alterar a VAR calculo no innerHTMl para 20px quando realizado o evento.

Answer (score 0):

Não existe apenas uma possibilidade de solução para a sua situação.
Uma maneira de resolver o seu problema é pré-definir algumas classes em CSS e a selecionar em [tempo de execução](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4023706/11379709) de acordo o resultado do cálculo.

Mudanças no código:

- Fiz algumas mudanças na [forma de declarar variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47165/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-declara%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-vari%C3%A1veis-usando-let-e-var).
- Adicionei duas variáveis:

  - `classificação` string que contém o texto de exibição do resultado correspondente ao IMC
  - `destaque` string que contém o nome da classe CSS que será aplica a parte do resultado exibido dependendo do valor do IMC.
- Ao montar o HTML que exibe o resultado utilizei um [template string](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/458012/137387)
- Dentro do template string utilizei um  cujo o [atributo  classe](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) seja definido de acordo ao IMC calculado.

```js
function IMC() {
  const peso = document.getElementById("peso");
  const altura = document.getElementById("altura");
  const resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
  let classificação = "Normal";
  let destaque = "normal";

  const p = Number(peso.value);
  const a = Number(altura.value);

  if (peso.value.length == 0 || altura.value.length == 0) {
    resultado.innerHTML = "Digite os dados nos inputs";
    return
  }
  let calculo = p / (a * a);
  if (calculo < 16) {
    classificação = "Sua classifição é Magreza Grau III procure um especialista";
    destaque = "critico";
  } else if (calculo >= 40) {
    classificação = "Sua classifição é Obesidade Mórbida procure um especialista";
    destaque = "critico";
  }
  resultado.innerHTML = `Seu IMC é de <span class="${destaque}">${calculo}</span><br><br>${classificação}.`;
}
```

```css
label {
  display: list-item;
  margin: 0.5em 0;
}

.critico {
  color: red;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.normal {
  color: black;
  font-size: normal;
}
```

```html
<label>Peso: <input type="number" name="peso" id="peso" step="10"></label>
<label>Altura: <input type="number" name="altura" id="altura" step="0.1"></label>
<button onclick="IMC()">Calcular IMC</button>
<p id="resultado">Resultado:</p>
```

Comment: Não achei o equivalente a https://stackoverflow.com/q/4023706/11379709 aqui no site. Se alguém souber o link.