# Como pular linha no JS?

Tags: javascript, quebras-de-linha

Quero pular linhas entre os `document.write()`

```js
var n1 = parseFloat(prompt('Digite um número: '));
var n2 = parseFloat(prompt('Digite outro número: '));
document.write('A soma desses números é: ', n1 + n2);
document.write('A subtração desses números é:', n1 + n2)
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Antes de dar um negativo, só peço que analisem o título e o conteúdo, e imaginem quantos iniciantes que digitarão no google `Como pular linha no JS?` ou algo similar e cairão aqui na pergunta, a lerão, se identificarão como tendo o mesmo problema e aqui obterão uma respostas? Esse é conceito de **utilidade**, a utilidade não é o aproveitamento imediato que um único individuo tem ao ler a pergunta, mas a utilidade mede o ganho que a sociedade(rebanho de novatos na area ou na linguagem) obterá com a existência dessa questão. Se discorda de mim ok, mas é caso para orientar construção da questão.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o elemento HTML [`<br>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) que é elemento HTML para quebra de linha.

```js
var n1 = 15.0;
var n2 = 23.0;
document.write(`A soma desses números é: ${n1 + n2}<br>`);
document.write(`A subtração desses números é: ${n1 - n2}`)
```

Veja que o método [`Document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/write) grava uma string na stream de um documento ou aberto por [`document.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/open) ou ao documento corrente.
O texto escrito é ​​analisado segundo o modelo de estrutura do documento. No seu caso a string é analisada como HTML e por consequência o texto `<br>` torna-se um nó, quebra de linha, do documento.

Outra possibilidade é adicionar o texto como parágrafos e assim obter um maior controle da estilização do elemento, por exemplo aqui foi personalizado os espaçamentos com a propriedade CSS [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/margin) e a cor de um dos parágrafos com a propriedade CSS [`color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/color).

```js
var n1 = 15.0;
var n2 = 23.0;
document.write(`<p>A soma desses números é: ${n1 + n2}</p>`);
document.write(`<p class="red">A subtração desses números é: ${n1 - n2}</p>`)
```

```css
p {
  /* topo | horizontal | inferior */
  margin: 0em auto 0.3em;
}

p.red {
  color: red;
}
```

Note que ao passar o texto como argumento de `document.write()` foi usado um [Template String](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/458004/o-cifr%C3%A3o-n%C3%A3o-funciona-para-interpolar-uma-string-em-javascript/458012#458012).

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

No HTML, utilize a tag de line-break [`<br/>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br). Em ambientes fora do HTML, use o `\n`.

```js
var n1 = parseFloat(prompt('Digite um número: '));
var n2 = parseFloat(prompt('Digite outro número: '));
document.write('A soma desses números é: ', n1 + n2, "<br/>");
document.write('A subtração desses números é:', n1 + n2)
```