# Como eu faço para carregar o resultado na mesma página?

Tags: javascript, html, button

Quando eu clico em somar, atualiza a página e aparece o resultado, mas não aparece o que está escrito em h1.
Como eu faço para carregar o resultado na mesma página, sem limpar o que está escrito em h1?

```js
function somar() {
  let soma = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
    soma = soma + i;
  document.write("Soma: " + soma);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Projeto: Soma de 1 até 1000</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Projeto: Somar de 1 até 1000 </h1>

  <button onclick="somar()">Somar</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1):

Como explicado pelo @bfavaretto nesse [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/541493/como-eu-fa%C3%A7o-para-carregar-o-resultado-na-mesma-p%C3%A1gina#comment972323_541496)

> O motivo disso ter de ser assim é que [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/write) sobrescreve todo
> o documento se for executado após o término do carregamento da página
> (e o script em questão só executa quando se clica o botão, o que
> necessariamente é após o carregamento).

Então uma alternativa ao uso do método `document.write()` é prever no layout da página em elemento que receberá o resultado da sua operação.
Nesse caso será usado um [elemento parágrafo](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p), vazio, cujo o [atributo id](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) será utilizado para localizar e referenciar esse elemento dentro do script através do método [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) e que posteriormente terá o texto modificado através da propriedade [`Node.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) usando um [Template String](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/458012/137387) com uma [expressão arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) embutida.

Antes de ir para o exemplo é importante ressaltar que para fazer a soma dos primeiros *n* números Naturais não é preciso soma-los individualmente, existe a fórmula dos [Números Triangulares](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_triangular) criada por Carl Friedrich Gauss que faz exatamente esse somatório:

[image: Somatório do n primeiros Naturais]

fazendo `n = 1000`

[image: Soma do 1000 primeiros números naturais]

```js
const resultado = document.getElementById("resultado"); //Obtém a referência para o elemento cujo o id é resultado.

function somar() {
  resultado.innerText = `Resultado: ${((n)=>n*(n+1)/2)(1000)}`; //Substitui o conteúdo textual do parágrafo resultado. 
  //resultado.innerText = `Resultado: ${1000*1001/2}`; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Projeto: Soma de 1 até 1000</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Projeto: Somar de 1 até 1000 </h1>
  <button onclick="somar()">Somar</button>
  <p id="resultado"></p> <!--Parágrafo vazio para ser preenchido pela função somar()-->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Ao invés de usar o `document.write` tente usar o método `append`:

```js
  document.getElementById("append").append("<br>Soma: " + soma);
```

Em seu `HTML` adicione um ID na tag `<h1>`, para podermos referenciar no arquivo JS

```html
  <h1 id="append">Projeto: Somar de 1 até 1000 </h1>
```

Comment: O motivo disso ter de ser assim é que document.write sobrescreve todo o documento se for executado  após o término do carregamento da página (e o script em questão só executa quando se clica o botão, o que necessariamente é após o carregamento). OBS: tem um erro de digitação, o correto é `getElementById`, com o último D minúsculo.

Comment: Verdade, acabei nem reparando, ótimo comentário e obrigado por avisar!

Answer (score -3):

Eu achei uma solução. Eu havia recriado o código com ES6, porém como não sei seu nível em programação fiz da mesma forma que você.

Algumas dicas para você pesquisar depois, caso ainda não conheça:

- Arrow functions
- Template Strings
- Addition assignment

Aqui está o código:

```js
// Aqui stou puxando a referência da tag <body> no HTML.
const body = document.body;

function soma() {

  let totalSoma = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {

    totalSoma = totalSoma + i;
  }

  // Aqui estou criando uma tag HTML, eu optei por criar uma tag <p>.
  let newElement = document.createElement("p");

  // Aqui vai ser o conteúdo que "newElement" vai armazenar.
  newElement.textContent = "Soma: " + totalSoma;

  // Com esse método o "newElement" vai ser adicionado no final, dentro da tag <body>
  body.append(newElement);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Projeto: Soma de 1 até 1000</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Projeto: Somar de 1 até 1000</h1>
  <button onclick="soma()">Somar</button>
</body>

</html>
```